# Override Access Denied route/path with Identity Server 4/asp.net core 2.2

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.2

Very new to Identity Server/ASP Identity, so I hope I explain the situation well enough.

I'm having an issue where my web apps attempt to navigate to an Account/AccessDenied controller and action if they are found to be unauthorized...but this  exact controller and action exist nowhere.

I've attempted the following, but I'm not so sure it's actually doing what I think it is

```cs
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = $"{config.IDServUrl}/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        options.LoginPath = $"{config.IDServUrl}/Identity/Account/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = $"{config.IDServUrl}/Identity/Account/Logout";

    });
```

My Controllers, or Actions within, have the `Authorize` Attribute, and I lock them down with a Policy. That part works fine, and if the user is authorized they are logged in/redirect into the app successfully.

What is happening right now if unauthorized:

1. go to the web app (an IDSrv client)
2. redirected to Identity Server
3. log into Identity Server
4. If unauthorized, a 404 error displays because it can't find `https://myapp/account/accessdenied`

`Account/AccessDenied` does not exist anywhere in my app, and neither does it exist in my Identity Server app. Identity Server uses `/Identity/Account/AccessDenied` if a user doesn't have access to something.

All of this is default - I haven't changed anything regarding this.

So what I am trying to figure out is either how to tell my app to go to `https://MyIDSrvApp/Identity/Account/AccessDenied` (since it already exists) or if I have to manually create an Account Controller with an AccessDenied Action in every single app that is secured with IDSrv.

I'm just a bit unclear on this behavior, how to best handle it, and where my apps are even getting this `/account/accessdenied` from in the first place since I'm not setting it manually anywhere.

Comment: Did you try configuring these paths in the authentication scheme for cookies within then `AddCookie()`? Also, I can at least tell you that the template for access denied url is `Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host + OriginalPathBase + targetPath;` where `targetPath` is your url in the option. This is from the default cookie auth handler (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationHandler.cs#L116).

Answer (score 6):

The default path for access denied is set in the cookie. Therefore, it's outside identity server. To Customise the access denied path use options on the AddCookie()

```
.AddCookie("Cookies", options => 
{
   options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/oops";
})
```